# Does $\Gamma$ intersect $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ transversely at $I$?

Tags: differential-topology

Identify the space of all $2 \times 2$ real matrices with $\mathbb{R}^4$ so that the matrix
$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\end{array} \right)$

corresponds to $(a, b, c, d)$.
Let $\Gamma$ denote the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^
4$ with equation $x_1 +x_2 +x_3 - x_4 = 0$.
Does $\Gamma$ intersect $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ transversely at $I$?�

Comment: Can you show your work? I don't know where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to begin.

Comment: What does it mean for two spaces to intersect transversely at a point?

Comment: I know that there tangent planes at the point of intersection must span the whole of $\mathbbR}^4$, but I am having a difficult time figuring out what those planes are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}=I$, we have $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}&=d=1,\\\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}&=-c=0,
\\\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}&=-b=0,\\\frac{\partial}{\partial d}\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}&=a=1.\end{align}$$
hence the tangent space to $SL$ at $I$ is the orthogonal space to $(1,0,0,1)$.
On the other hand $\Gamma$ is th eorthogonal space to $(1,1,1,-1)$, hence these two tangent sapces span all of $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Sorry.  I wrote the wrong thing down.